# Is PhD program in the US universities fully funded especially in Stem programs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding

I am asking this question because I am considering applying for PhD in Electrical and electronics engineering in US.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x)

Comment: For my university, yes, basically all the Ph.D. students have financial support. TA, RA, or fellowship.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no automatic "funding". But what is normally available to most doctoral students in STEM fields is a Teaching Assistantship or possibly a Research Assistantship, in which you spend several hours per week assisting in either a course or a lab, respectively.

These are common but not automatic. An international student might need appropriate language skills to qualify.

Also note that these are common in most STEM fields because there is a need for assistance. For example, in a Math program the TAs assist in the huge undergraduate math program. In some lab fields there is a need for a lot of lab assistants to aid with research. I don't know specifically how this applies to engineering fields, however and it would depend on the university and its overall program.

Either a TA or an RA will cover both tuition and a modest stipend for living expenses. Without either, you normally need to pay tuition, which can be very high.

Answer (score 1):

PhD programs in STEM in the US are usually fully funded. Sometimes this funding comes from the university and you are expected to teach or TA a certain number of classes each year. Sometimes it comes from the faculty member you are doing research with. In either case, it is more like a job than a scholarship: You effectively earn your stipend and tuition waivers by doing work for the university or your professor.